# itration behaviour when list length = 1

Tags: python-2.6

I'm quite new to python and am having issues with for loop behaviour. In my code I'm reading config from a file using configobj. The contents of the config file are variable and that is where I'm seeing issues.

Here's my test code:

```
if webconf.has_key(group):
        scenario_list = webconf[group]['Scenarios']['names']

        for scenario in scenario_list:

              print "Scenario name = %s\n" % scenario
```

The "scenario_list" variable will contain any number of strings. When 'names' has multiple elements "scenario" is set to the value of each element, which is fine. When "names" has only 1 element then the loop iterates over each character of the first entry, breaking my code.

So, how do I get the for loop simply to return the value of the entry in "scenario_list" when list length is 1?

Thankyou in advance for any advice offered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tuples rather than lists?

```
aTuple = (1,2,3)
aList = [1,2,3]
```

The big difference between tuples and lists are that tuples are immutable and lists are mutable. That is, with a list you may change the element of a list, or even add and remove elements.

The problem that you are likely encountering is related to a concept called tuple unpacking.

```
aList = [0] # aList is now [0]
notATuple = (0) # notATuple is now 0 
# there was exactly one element in the tuple, so it was unpacked in the variable
aTuple = (0,) # aTuple is now (0,) - a tuple with one element
# the comma indicates that you wish that the tuple should not be unpacked
```

The only other problem I think of is that you are not putting the scenario string in a list or tuple when you have only one scenario. Python treats strings like lists (well, more like tuples) of characters. As such, if you iterate over a string you get the individual characters (the behaviour you experienced). Hence, you must put your scenario string in a list (or tuple) if want to iterate over your one string, and not its characters. Had you not been using strings you would have seen a runtime error.

Comment: Looking at the return type of the configobj object I see it returns a list when there are multiple elements to an item and a string when there is one. Are you saying I should do something like this..."for scenario in list(scenario_list):"...

Comment: I think i have it now. By changing the for loop declaration to "for scenario in [scenario_list]" I'm now getting the behaviour I want. Thanks for your help in getting me thinking in the right way:)

Comment: Aah, I spoke too soon! That declaration breaks the multiple element behaviour when the return type is a list:(

Comment: That's annoying behaviour (not returning a list when only one element). You'll need to use an if statement and branch depending on if you have a list or a string. `isinstance(scenario_list, basestring)` will return true if you have a string and otherwise false.